# How can I calculate RenderTransformOrigin criteria of other control?

Tags: c#, wpf, rendertransform

I want to calculate 'RenderTransformOrigin' criteria of other control.
Please look at this image, because I do not speak English well.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9GSv.png)

There boxes placed at same level. not child, not parent.
The green box is theoretically parent.
so all control's RenderTransformOrigin are same location to green box.
but I think RenderTransformOrigin is local coordinate system.

I want to calculate RenderTransformOrigin...

thanks you

**EDIT**
I'm currently tried this way....

Center point (local coordinate system?)

> ItemHeight * CriteriaItem.OriginY
>   ItemWidth * CriteriaItem.OriginX

Calculate (CenterPoint is above result)

> CenterPoint.X / TargetBoxWidth 
>   CenterPoint.Y / TargetBoxHeight

Final
Convert TargetBox's locar coordinate system)

> Cavnas.TranslatePoint( CalculatedPoint, TargetBox)

**EDIT**
I solved in above way.
Extension method

```
    public static Point GetCenterPoint(this UIElement item, UIElement target)
    {
        return item.TranslatePoint(
                    new Point(item.Width * item.RenderTransformOrigin.X, item.Height * item.RenderTransformOrigin.Y), target);
    }

    public static Point GetRenderTransformOrigin(this Point p, double h, double w)
    {
        return new Point(p.X / w, p.Y / h);
    }
```

usage

```
RenderTransformOrigin = GetCenterPoint(BaseItem).GetRenderTransformOrigin(ChildItem.Height, ChildItem.Width);
```

but....

When I changed 'RenderTransformOrigin' this rotate and position changed....

When the rotation is finished, 
find a way to keep the rotating object without RotateTransform.

help me.

thans you.